# how to map server response for errors and success

Tags: angular

I am trying to make a custom validator for my Angular 9 project.

this is the validator method

```
public static validatName(service: MyService): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => service.searchNumber(control.value)
      .pipe(
        map((response) => response ? null : { notFound: true })
      );
  }
```

when the server response with a 404 error code, the map it's not executed and my form control doesn't get the validation null/not found needed.

How can I map my server response, either 200 success or any error.
When I get 200 it should retrieve null otherwise notFound: true
At the moment, only the 200 status code scenario works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch an exception.

```
public static validatName(service: MyService): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => service.searchNumber(control.value)
      .pipe(
        map((response) => null),
        catchError(() => of({ notFound: true })),  // here
      );
  }
```